# Upgrade from 5.9 to 5.16 in Drupal - upgrade script won't run

Tags: upgrade

I have Drupal 7 on Krystal Hosting, with CiviCRM v5.9 and trying to upgrade to v5.16. I've followed the upgrade steps on the docs.civicrm.org site and got to the step where it says,

"Or, point your web browser to the following URL and follow the on-screen instructions.

http://example.org/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1"

I've tried replacing "example.org" with my site address but just getting page not found.

I've checked I'm logged into **Drupal** as an admin. Only difference in address bar is text after site is **?=civicrm/upgrade?reset=1** instead of just **/civicrm/upgrade?reset=1**. When I click to go into **Civicrm** after extracting/installing 5.16, I get "Website encountered unexpected error" so I can't get to **CiviCRM >> Admin >> System Status**. Are there error logs anywhere with anything more helpful than "unexpected error" ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, are you logged in as an admin already? Then, if yes, if you click on CiviCRM on the left and look in the address bar, is there anything between "example.org" and "civicrm"? If there is you also need to have that in the upgrade url.

Answer (score 4):

If you go to CiviCRM's **Administer menu » Administration Console » System Status** you should see an error "Database Upgrade Needed".  There should be a link you can press that should bring you to the upgrade page.  This link should account for issues like those mentioned by @Demerit.  Please edit your question if this doesn't resolve the issue.